# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, vagrant, homestead

Running a Laravel Homestead Vagrant box which is using PHP 5.6. The database is an sqlite file. I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 14 unable to open database file
```

This occurs when attempting to insert login data in the database.

Both the database file and the containing folder are set to 777 permissions so I don't think this is a permissions issue, I have tried removing the containing folder and recreating the database to no avail.

Comment: Can you perform other queries on the database?

Comment: I can query from DB Browser for SQLite but not from Laravel

Comment: Are you sure your credentials match in that case?

Comment: Guaranteed. I should add that my app is also in production and I am using the DB downloaded from production, but my local version has been re-cloned recently. This setup worked as recently as last week.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution to this was to change the permissions on the host machine and not inside the Vagrantbox terminal.

Comment: in my case I had the same problem until I provided permissions also to a folder which contains that DB file

Answer (score 3):

give the folder of the sqlite file to web owner or set full access

```
chown -R username:group folder_of_sqlite_file
```

or

```
chmod -R 777 folder_of_sqlite_file
```